# result repetition in SQL inner join with one to many relationship

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join, one-to-many

I am implementing an application that provides the opening hours of several venues. A simplified version of my DB implementation consists of two tables:

```
+-----------+    +------------------+
|    Venue  |    |    opening_hour  |
+-----------+    +------------------+
|  venue_id |    |  opening_hour_id |
|    name   |    |        day       |
+-----------+    |  close_time      |
                 |  open_time       |
                 |  venue_id        |
                 +------------------+
```

In this case there is a one-to-many relationship between venue and opening hour.

Now, I would like to retrieve a list of all venues available in the database and their corresponding opening hours. To solve this problem I am using the following code:

```
SELECT  ven.name as name, oh.day as day
FROM venue ven INNER JOIN opening_hour oh
ON oh.venue_id = ven.venue_id
```

With this implementation, for each day's opening hours I get a row result with the venue name and the day value. This means that if a venue is opened 6 days a week, I would receive 6 rows with the same name and the corresponding day. As a result I find myself with a lot of repeated data that I have to manipulate on the server side.

The only two solutions I can think of from my small DB knowledge is to either follow the current solution or to extract all venues and then perform a single query for each one of them in order to extract their opening hours. The latter one is clearly the worse solution since it would require a ridiculous amount of DB requests.

Can anyone thing of a better approach? The ideal would be to receive a row containing the venue name and an array formed by all the opening hours.

note: Not sure if this is relevant in this case, but I am using a PostgreSQL database.

Comment: add `distinct` after `select`?..

Comment: @VaoTsun, nope, some kind of GROUP BY is needed.

Comment: then `string_agg(opening_hour,',') over (partition by oh.venue_id)`

Comment: @VaoTsun Where should I put that code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give the venue name and an array of all days when the venue is open:

```
SELECT ven.name, array_agg(oh.day)
FROM venue ven
     NATURAL JOIN opening_hour oh
GROUP BY ven.name;
```

Comment: what if I wanted to put the full table details in the array_agg() function?

Comment: You can use something like `array_agg(ROW(oh.day, oh.close_time, oh.open_time))` if you want.

Answer (score 0):

For the ones using MSSQL;

```
SELECT
    v.name,
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('['+(
        SELECT
            '''' + convert(nvarchar(max),s2.open_time) + '''' as a
        FROM opening_hour s2
        WHERE s2.venue_id= s.venue_id 
        FOR XML PATH('')
     ) + ']','<a>',''),'</a>',','),',]',']') as opening_hours
FROM opening_hour s
INNER JOIN Venue v on v.venue_id = s.venue_id
GROUP BY s.venue_id,v.name
```

Just to note here, this does not return data type Array. It is just a string in a array format.